# Retaining items created during setup of a python test

Tags: python, django, testing, django-testing, django-tests

I'm writing a test suite for a custom manager in Django, and want to test a large number of items.

Essentially, it requires creating several thousand items, due to a combinatorial explosion.

What I need is a way to create a *lot* of django objects in the database and have them retained through the whole test class instead of recreating them.

I have the following code:

```
class CustomConceptQuerySetTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass #make lots and lots of items.

    def test_is_public(self):
        pass # check if returned items in the object.public() queryset are actually "public"
    def test_is_editable(self):
        pass # check if returned items in the object.viewable() queryset are actually "viewable" only to certain users.
```

Unfortunately, `setUp` is called before each test, but the content is not changed during tests, only read, and is the same each time.

Is there a way in Django to keep the database, or prevent rollbacks or destruction within a test Class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`setUpClass()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass) *class method*:

```
class CustomConceptQuerySetTest(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        ...
```

Comment: Oh gosh, that was simple.